# Which set of Riemannian metrics is compact in the manifold of Riemannian metrics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Suppose M is a compact manifold and Met(M) is the Frechet manifold of all Riemannian metrics on M, does there exist a set of metrics with distinguished properties (e.g. metrics with constant scalar or ricci curvatures) which is compact in Met(M)?

Comment: Rescaling by small (or large) constants shows that one needs size bounds to achieve Gromov-Hausdorff compactness. An upper diameter and lower injectivity radius bounds rule out rescaling. Then there is a matter of regularity to upgrade Gromov-Hausdorff to $C^\infty$ convergence (I assume you use $C^\infty$ topology on the space of metrics) which works for Einstein manifolds with bounded Einstein constants. Thus the class of Einstein metrics with uniform above bound on diameter, lower bound on injectivity radius, and two-sided bound on Einstein constant is compact in the $C^\infty$ topology.

Comment: For more on this topic see P.Petersen article in MSRI comparison geometry book at http://library.msri.org/books/Book30/contents.html.

Comment: Igor, thanks, it was very helpful.

Comment: A correction: the compactness I talked about is up to isometry, that is the set of isometry classes of Einstein manifolds with the above geometric restrictions is compact. Orbits of the diffeomorphism group action by pullback are noncompact.

Comment: I see, thank you.